# When are controller methods called in WD4A?

Tags: methods, controller, abap, webdynpro

Can someone explain to me when methods are called in WD4A applications? Particularly methods that are defined in the application controller (and not the view (controllers)).
I'm looking at some sample codes and there's this supply_unit method in the componentcontroller which basically reads a few values from a table and puts these in the controller context so they are available in view_2, based on a context node that was assigned a value by the user on view_1.

But I don't see at which point this method actually get's called (the application actually has more than only these two views) and how the application knows that it needs to be called so everything can be shown in view_2

Comment: This is a rather general question that is very hard to answer unless you give a specific example. I'd suggest you have a look at the online documentation avaliable at https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/03/0048413e466e24e10000000a155106/frameset.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP's standard documentation for WebDynpro is pretty good, and goes through all of this. This [page](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/1e/75e3d86397bc4db8f579d9f020f661/content.htm) (and the pages below it) describe programming controller methods in general. I would suggest taking a couple days and working through all of the WebDynpro for ABAP documentation, coding examples as you go. You'll have a much more complete understanding that way.

Methods should be implemented in the component controller (as opposed to the view controller) when the logic of that method is used (or may be used) across multiple views. For example, if you have a context node thats displayed in multiple nodes (like a list of units of measure), it makes sense to program it's supply method once in the controller, instead of in each view.

Your question seemed to be more about supply functions (SUPPLY_UNIT sounds like the name of a supply function). These are methods that are called automatically by the system the first time a context node is read. They are used to initialize contents of the node. More info can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/f1/177741adb7167de10000000a155106/content.htm).

Comment: I wasn't realizing that I was supposed to add a supply function to my node. Thanks!